# any utility on centos 6 to sound an alarm when power is low

Tags: centos, power-management, hibernate

Is there an application that will set an audible alarm when the battery goes low on a centos 6 IBM 430 machine?
Details of the problem here:
I have set it hibernate when battery is low. However, it does not hibernate possibly because most of the time I am working in a full screen windows VM that prevents it from going to hibernate when I try to do it manually.

Since I am not able to see the battery levels (I am working in a full screen windows VM), the nmachine switches off when battery goes low. So I lose all my data and in one instance, the VMs (I am running windows and ubuntu) got corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google throws this up:

[Check your battery status from the command line](http://www.garron.me/go2linux/laptop-battery-status-with-linux-console-command-acpi.html)

A suggestion might be to parse out the percentage remaining of the battery charge, and play a sound when it falls to a certain low water mark/threshold.  You could then run this from cron/at every few minutes or so.  Very rudimentary but...

cheers

sc.